# SO tag synonym proposal: [rtl] -> [right-to-left]

Tags: support, stack-overflow, tag-synonyms, synonym-request

Suggest Stack Overflow tag **rtl** to be a synonym of tag **right-to-left**.

- [right-to-left](/questions/tagged/right-to-left) (65 questions tagged as of now)
  description: none
- [rtl](/questions/tagged/rtl) (172 questions tagged as of now)
  description:

  > Right to left (rtl) is a way of UI to present data for countries that are writing and reading from the right to the left instead from the left to the right...

Comment: [RTL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Register_transfer_level) has other meanings on the EE side.  Since Verilog and VHDL are fair game here, I'd be careful with that.  Just something to consider.

Comment: @JeffMercado in that case I would say the wiki should probably be updated.

Comment: Came across this while retagging some "direction" stuff. Problem still exists.

Comment: Why not retagging [tag:rtl] questions, wich are related to *right-to-left*, to [tag:right-to-left] and keep [tag:rtl] (and update tag-wiki) for questions related to verilog (6 questions) & vhdl (3 questions) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've retagged [rtl](/questions/tagged/rtl) questions wich are related to *right-to-left*, with the tag [right-to-left](/questions/tagged/right-to-left). Others questions are relatd to *register transfer level*, I think.

I've copy/pasted (and updated) old wiki tag from [rtl](/questions/tagged/rtl) to [right-to-left](/questions/tagged/right-to-left).

And I've [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/2259288) [an edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/2259289) for [rtl](/questions/tagged/rtl) to match *Register-transfer-level* instead of *right to left*.

Comment: I profoundly enjoyed [rejection message](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/2259288) in one of the edits "The MSO question has not yet been resolved, so an edit seems premature." Yeah sure, this crappy ambiguity has been reported `Feb 18 '12 at 18:46`, almost 1.5 freaking years ago, for how long it was going to hang in there "unresolved". Hats off for having guts to make a move