# Do something clever with the [bidi] and [bidirectional] tags

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, synonym-request

The [bidirectional](/questions/tagged/bidirectional) tag can refer to both bidirectional text (such as Arabic and Hebrew), and to bidirectional relations in databases and data structures, which are supposed to be covered by the [bidirectional-relation](/questions/tagged/bidirectional-relation) tag.

I'm not sure what to do with them. Both topics are reasonably common. I would probably make the existing [bidi](/questions/tagged/bidi) tag a synonym of [rtl](/questions/tagged/rtl). What to do with [bidirectional](/questions/tagged/bidirectional)? It should probably a synonym, but I'm not sure for what.

Comment: related to [tag:rtl] - [SO tag synonym proposal: \[rtl\] -> \[right-to-left\]](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/122772/so-tag-synonym-proposal-rtl-right-to-left)

Comment: If `bidi` isn't unambiguous, then you have to clean that up first before we get to tag cleanups.  First things first (I poppa)...

Comment: I'm not an expert on this, but from what I understand it's not really correct to say that RTL and bidi are the same thing. Arabic and Hebrew are RTL scripts, and bidi refers to mixing LTR with RTL.

Comment: @hammar, I do happen to be an expert on the subject of bidi and rtl, and I can say that this is the same topic. Arabic, Hebrew and all the other right-to-left languages are essentially bidirectional, because all texts in them are assumed to be mixing native letters with numbers and left-to-right quotations.

Comment: @AmirE.Aharoni: Ok. Thanks for clearing that up. Consider my objection withdrawn :)

Comment: @casperOne, I looked at all the questions tagged as "bidi". Luckily, there are only 33 of them. They are all on the topic of RTL.

Comment: @AmirE.Aharoni Looking at the tag for "bidi", it means text going in both directions, while RTL is text going in *one* direction.  I think that making these synonyms would be a bad thing.

Comment: @casperOne, see my reply to hammar above.